# @Override annotation error

Tags: android, overriding

I get an error on every line that has the `@Override` annotation.

For example, the following message appears as the error popup:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - The method onClick(DialogInterface, int) 
>      of type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must 
>      override a superclass method
>     - implements 
>      android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick

The Compiler compliance level is set to *1.7*.

I've read that this problem was occurring when *eclipse* defaults to *1.5* and it should be set to *1.6*. But in the case of *1.7* what would the solution be?

Also, can I just remove the `@Override` annotation and be trouble free?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: I would like to but it's copyrighted and it strictly forbids to post the code on forums.

Comment: When you override the OnClickListener you must make sure the arguments are defined exactly as the interface describes, otherwise you will get an Override error.

Comment: "The Compiler compliance level is set to 1.7" -- no, it is not, at least not for this project. It is set for 1.5.

Comment: I was referring to what I viewed in the preference settings.  Where else can I see this?

Comment: CommonsWare, I see what you meant.  I checked the project specific settings and you are correct.  It is set to 1.5.  I find the eclipse IDE quite confusing.  But thanks for you pointing this out to me.

Comment: I set the project specific setting for Compiler Compliance Level 1.7 and the errors went away.